# Angular 5, Iterate through firebase realtime database

Tags: angular, loops, angular5

I have a firebase realtime database that it's structure is like this:
[image: Firebase realtime database]

The images and services nodes are fixed and will not be changed but inside images the user can add more nodes (random names) and inside each node is multiple json object as you can see in the image.

I want to iterate through the images node and find all the child nodes and iterate through each child node to show the pictures.

what I did was creating a property to read the images node:

```
this.wholeAlbum = this.afDb.list('/images').valueChanges();
```

but I can not figure out what to write in the html to do the iteration.
I used this code to iterate but shows nothing (I only want to iterate through the first node of the images node "newyear" and display all the json objects inside it):

```
<div *ngFor="let w of wholeAlbum[0] | async; let i = index">
    <p>{{w}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use ngFor to iterate data in HTML. https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngfor/

Comment: I did use iteration but it doesn't work as I expected. see the updated post.

Comment: @FoadJesus avoid using *ngFor in an anchor tag, instead, you can try ngFor in the div above. also make sure you are getting some value in wholeAlbum[0] by printing {{wholeAlbum[0]}} beside the div

Comment: I get no results for wholeAlbum[0], but how can I access each node inside Images that the user may add in the future with unpredictable name.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer,

I changed the way I get the data and this time I subscribed to it:

```
this.afDb.list('/images/').valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
  this.wholeAlbum = <IImage[]>items;
});
```

and I was able to iterate like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let w of wholeAlbum; let i = index">
    <div *ngFor="let x of w">{{i + ': ' + x.src}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this is problem in accessing nested object,

```
this.wholeAlbum = this.afDb.list('/images').valueChanges();
//inside images 

<div *ngFor="let w of wholeAlbum">
   <div *ngFor="let value of w.q13">
      <p>{{value.src}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps, [check this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqhfzs?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) you can get idea to access nested objects

Comment: The problem is sometimes I even don't know the name of the nodes, in here we are accessing the node through it's name "q13", but sometimes when the user add a node we don't know it's name.

Comment: think thats not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrive the datas from firebase realtime database using snapshotChanges() and valueChanges()

This is the way that i am using

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
var scope;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-coupons',
  templateUrl: './coupons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./coupons.component.css']
})
export class CouponsComponent implements OnInit {
  images : any =[]; 
  constructor(
    private afDb: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { 
    scope=this;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  getData() {
    this.afDb.list('settings',query=>query.child('q13')).snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(values=>{
      this.images = [];
        if(values) {
         values.map(val=>{
           scope.images.push(val.payload.val());
        });
       }
    });

  }

}
```

html code--

```
<div *ngFor="let img of images">
   {{img.src}}
</div>
```